# How to debug mystery ENOTFOUND?

Tags: node.js

I am getting random restarts on a PM2 managed nodejs cluster.  The only symptom I get on the error log is of the following pattern - an ENOTFOUND on dns.js.

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND walkinto.inhttp walkinto.inhttp:80
>      at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
>      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

Clearly the problem is a malformed server name - **walkinto.inhttp** is incorrect and it should be **walkinto.in** .  The challenge is that this is not a host name hard coded in the code.  There are many places in this fairly large code base that makes name resolution and it is of dynamic nature.

I have spent considerable time to pinpoint the root cause but so far have had no luck.  I need help to print more log information from dns.js; probably a call stack 'may' would help to move forward.

Q1 : How to enable more detailed logging on nodejs core modules?

Q2 : What could cause a nodejs restart to happen for an ENOTFOUND?  How to avoid a restart - This path is not desirable.

Q3: Are there any other smarter way to trouble shoot this problem?

Comment: Could you include the code that leads to this error? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No.  I have no clue on the origin of this error.  I have tried to add error handlers and logs to all suspect looking code - http.get , http.post request() ...

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no way for us to help you solve the issue without some code to go on, I'll answer your questions:

> How to enable more detailed logging on nodejs core modules?

Run node with the `inspect` option and attach to the debugger with Chrome DevTools or another application. See these links:
https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

> What could cause a nodejs restart to happen for an ENOTFOUND? How to avoid a restart - This path is not desirable.

The Node runtime isn't restarting. The error you're seeing is generated from something similar to `` throw new Error(`getaddrinfo ${err}`) ``, and any uncaught error from `throw` will crash the runtime.
The restart is happening because you run the app via PM2, and can be disabled by passing the `--no-autorestart` option to PM2. If you want to avoid the application from crashing, you should wrap whatever code that this could be generated from in a `try/catch`-block, and try to recover from the error.

> Are there any other smarter way to trouble shoot this problem?

This is most likely not an issue with the `dns` stdlib module. If I understand correctly, you are performing name resolutions on dynamically generated data, and that is most likely your issue. Somewhere in the code you have one or more functions that are either not validating the generated data or are generating invalid data due to a bug. We can't help you solve that unfortunately, since you haven't provided any code to go on. Would be great if you could try to pinpoint what code might cause this and update the question with it.

Comment: The process that is restarting does not have any server side thread routines.  It only handles REST calls.  Probably around 30~40 different APIs.  Daily transaction volume is 50-60k calls.  It is in use on a few thousand websites.  Apart from the restart patterns I can see on the server side there are no observed failed calls.  If I could get a call stack of this failure It will be of great help to identify the origin - async call :( .  Any way to make core libraries spit more logs?  Attaching a debugger to a production process to debug a non-critical error might not be appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error in my request that was something like this:

```
var optionsSearch = {
 host: 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com',
 path: '_api/search/query?querytext="sharepoint"',
  method: 'GET'
};
```

All did was removing the `https://` leaving only `mysite.sharepoint.com` and it was fixed.

Comment: I need to try it. Thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: My pleasure! Thank you! Let me know how it goes for you! @WalkInto